# One-to-many CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\NoSuchPropertyException

Tags: php, symfony, orm

Trying to set up two simple objects `Purchase` and `Address`.

One Purchase can have multiple Addresses (purchase address, invoice address)

Simplified ORM from Address Entity looks like:

```
X\Entity\Address:
    repositoryClass: X\Repository\AddressRepository
    type: entity
    manyToOne:
        purchase:
            targetEntity: Purchase
            inversedBy: addresses
            joinColumn:
                name: purchase_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        firstname:
            type: string
            length: 255
        email:
            type: string
            length: 255
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Simplified ORM from Purchase Entity looks like:

```
X\Entity\Purchase:
    repositoryClass: X\Repository\PurchaseRepository
    type: entity
    oneToMany:
        addresses:
            targetEntity: Address
            mappedBy: purchase
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        quantity:
            type: integer
        orderedAt:
            type: datetime
        toBeDeliveredAt:
            type: datetime
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Now these lines from the Purchase Class give me error

```
/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getAddresses()
{
    return $this->addresses;
}
```

**saying:**

> Neither the property "address" nor one of the methods "getAddress()",
>   "address()", "isAddress()", "hasAddress()", "__get()" exist and have
>   public access in class "X\Entity\Purchase".

Which is absolutely correct, there is no Property `address` and there aren't any methods for that non existing property.

Problem is kind of the Property name is `addresses` and there is a method `getAddresses` but something goes wrong with that.

Now the question is why is "the system" (symfony?) searching for a property name `address`? And of course how can I solve this?

**Update**

The error occurs on form submission. The Controller looks like this:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $purchase = new Purchase();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($purchase)
            ->add('address', AddressType::class)
            ->add('quantity', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('toBeDeliveredAt', DateType::class)
            ->add('comment', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($purchase);
            $em->flush();
        }


        return $this->render('X:Default:index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

And the AddressType looks like this:

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class);
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

If needed the entire Purchase Class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace X\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Purchase
 */
class Purchase
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $orderedAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $toBeDeliveredAt;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $delivered;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $deliveredAt;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $payd;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $paydAt;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $comment;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $addresses;

    /**
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity
     * @return Purchase
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Set orderedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $orderedAt
     * @return Purchase
     */
    public function setOrderedAt($orderedAt)
    {
        $this->orderedAt = $orderedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get orderedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getOrderedAt()
    {
        return $this->orderedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $toBeDeliveredAt
     */
    public function setToBeDeliveredAt($toBeDeliveredAt)
    {
        $this->toBeDeliveredAt = $toBeDeliveredAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getToBeDeliveredAt()
    {
        return $this->toBeDeliveredAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param Address $address
     * @return Address
     */
    public function addAddress(Address $address)
    {
        $this->addresses[] = $address;
        if($address->getPurchase() !== $this) {
            $address->setPurchase($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAddresses()
    {
        return $this->addresses;
    }
}
```

Comment: When have you this error ?

Comment: @DOZ on form submission, will include the parts in the question

Comment: @DOZ question is updated with Controller indexAction and the AddressType...

Comment: I'm not sure but why not using  ->add('addresses')?

Comment: @goto aaaaaaah *#\\+*! that's it! Beginner mistakes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from `->add('address', AddressType::class)` in your PurchaseType.

Try this:

```
->add('addresses', AddressType::class)
```

Comment: why CollectionType?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. But I was able to resolve this.

Just check your entity.orm.yml file and remove the field from `form` fields on which you are creating relations.

```
 $builder->add('question')->add('demographicYesNo')->add('questionSetId')->add('questionOptionTypeId')->add('questionSliderRange');
```

So, I have removed

> add('questionSetId')->add('questionOptionTypeId')

As I was creating relation on this field and symfony by default add this in Form .

Thanks,

Anirudh Sood.